# How Do I Parse a String?

Tags: bash, script, parsing, string-manipulation

I am new to bash, and I am creating a script that loops through the files in a directory and based on part of the filename, does something with the file, so far I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="/Users/me/Documents/import/*"
for f in "$DIR"
do
  t=??????
  echo "Loading $f into $t..."
done
```

so `$f` will output something like this: `/Users/me/Documents/import/time_dim-1272037430173`  out of this, I want `t` to equal `time_dim`, the directory can be variable length and `-1272037430173` is a fixed length (it's the unix timestamp btw).

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Untested:

```
t=`basename $f | sed -e 's/-[0-9]\+$//'`
```

Comment: it's close, it's returning `time_dim-1272037429351`

Comment: Try edited version above (`+` changed to `\+` in accordance with GNU sed regular expression documentation)

Comment: still doesn't work, but i got this to: `t=`basename $f | sed 's/-[^-]*$//'``

Comment: the only problem i am having is that `t` is concatenating all of it before executing the echo, so I get something like: `Loading /Users/me/Documents/import/* into date_dim demographic_dim event_log_facts ip_dim location_dim referal_dim time_dim` rather than `Loading /Users/me/Documents/import/time_dim-1272037430173 into time_dim...` etc etc

Comment: Oh, I don't think you're actually looping over the files.  Try removing the quotes around $DIR: `for f in $DIR` ....  Personally, I would say `DIR=/Users/me/Documents/import` (so that $DIR is just a directory, as its name suggests) and then `for f in $DIR/*` but that's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

you could also do:
`` $ t=`basename $f|tr -d '[0-9-]'` ``
or
`` $ t=`basename $f|gawk -F- '{print $1;}'` ``

edited: i misread the question

Answer (score 0):

```
What is the best way to go about this?
```

the "best" way, using just bash internals, :)

```
$ s=/Users/me/Documents/import/time_dim-1272037430173
$  echo ${s%-*}
/Users/me/Documents/import/time_dim
$ t=${s%-*}
$ echo ${t##*/}
time_dim
```